# Bitnami AMI connect MySQL Workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, bitnami

Im trying to connect mySQL workbench to my Bitnami AMI. I enter in the following information but get no luck.

[image]

in the SSH Password I enter in the password from the Bitnami cloud hosting properties screen.  Does anyone know why I cant connect?

MySQL is running on server 127.0.0.1 using port 3306. Please help.

Comment: Where did you get that hostname? (XXXX.bitnamiapp.com)

Comment: its on the Bitnami server management console

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any error you got, so it's a bit guessing, but from your settings I see you have used a Putty ssh key. This will not work. MySQL Workbench needs an OpenSSH key (actually paramiko, the underlying library). You can use Putty to convert your key to an OpenSSH variant.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm it works with the .pem key obtained from AWS.

Alternatively, you could follow the instructions here: https://wiki.bitnami.com/cloud/how_to_connect_to_your_amazon_instance#How_to_connect_to_MySQL_remotely.3f

Basically, you create a tunnel via Putty through which you can connect in workbench as if it was a local connection:

> Using Putty, you can first configure your connection as described this page, but before openning the connection, first got to the Putty Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels section and enter the values below, and then click add:
>
> ```
> Source port: 33306 
> Destination: localhost:3306
> ```
>
> Then start the SSH connection.
>
> Now you can configure your MySQL client in the following way:
>
> ```
> port: 33306
> hostname: localhost
> login: root
> password: <learn more>
> ```
>
> (Here's the [learn more](https://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/FAQ#What_is_the_MySQL_password.3f) link for the password)

Give the .pem key a try first, though... much easier...